# Find location in object

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV and I am able to find object from image in my case the business card. I need to extract specific location (email address, full name).

I tried to find specific location using morphologic operations and `cv2.findContours()` function but it does not deliver desired results because of contours size, lighting conditions.

[image]

I have:

- Always same object business card with same design
- Object width and height is always same (85 × 55 mm)

I need:

- To find specific location in image (email address, name)

[image]

Comment: "Object width and height is always same (85 × 55 mm)" well, that's not true of the image in pixels so it's sort of irrelevant. Either way, I think you're going about this the wrong way. I would use [feature detection to find an homography](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) between the template (business card scan) and the actual object. This will allow you to get the object into the same coordinates as the plain business card, and then you know exactly where the info on the card is.

Comment: What about detect the qr code and use it as landmark to warp the image and estimate the coordinates of each data field?

Comment: And @Doleron points at a similar idea that can also be easily implemented; whether you use feature detection or you define your own feature via the QR code, get the coordinates of the pieces you want as an ROI on the template and warp an image into the coordinates of that template to grab the info. Luckily, this problem is specific enough to get really good success here.